# Issue with arrow directions in quiver plot using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't know why the direction of the encircled arrows is like this. In the list `I4`, it is clearly well defined: `[(1, 0), (1, -1)]` and `[(0, -1), (1, -1)]`. Also, how do I adjust the arrow size?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#creating arrow
I4 = [[(0, 0), (1, 0)], [(0, 0), (0, -1)], [(1, 0), (1, -1)], [(0, -1), (1, -1)]]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,5))
for i in range(0,len(I4)):
    ax.quiver(*I4[i][0], *I4[i][1])  
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The arrows are defined as `[position, direction_vector]`. The direction vector determines where they point. If you want to define them based on an angle instead you can write it as `[(x, y), (math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle))]`.

Comment: because ` aux =[(1, 0), (1, -1)], ` with `ax.quiver(*aux[0],*aux[1]) ` in quiver means the point `[1,0]` with an arrow with shape `[1,-1]` (right-down)  this is the point in the upper circle. You're using bad quiver